# Fortran read from .dat file: date, time, 42 x real_values

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have some problem with reading a file and printing in another file.
The problem is that if I use formatted file, someowhere on the second line, the format is not good, since there is a minus on some values.
So depending on the line, the format is changing. The two lines are just an example. But the date and time will remain the same format always.

My file is like this:

```
22/03/2015 00:00:43 2.50E+4 1.66E+3 2.22E+3 2.70E+3 3.16E+3 3.83E+3 3.58E+3 3.69E+3 3.64E+3 2.45E+2 1.67E+2 3.64E+1 1.56E+1 7.47E+0 3.21E+0 2.09E+0 1.48E+0 1.39E+0 7.75E-1 7.20E-1 6.05E-1 6.45E-1 4.90E-1 3.65E-1 3.30E-1 1.46E-1 1.09E-1 6.10E-2 4.90E-2 4.10E-2 1.00E-2 9.00E-3 4.00E-3 1.00E-3 0.00E+0 0.00E+0 0.00E+0 0.00E+0 0.00E+0 0.00E+0 0.00E+0 0.00E+0
22/03/2015 16:14:35 1.26E+4 8.36E+2 1.12E+3 1.36E+3 1.59E+3 1.92E+3 1.80E+3 1.85E+3 1.83E+3 1.23E+2 8.36E+1 2.05E+1 9.87E+0 5.02E+0 2.84E+0 1.88E+0 1.49E+0 1.72E+0 1.06E+0 8.34E-1 8.22E-1 5.72E-1 4.61E-1 2.22E-1 2.78E-1 3.59E-1 2.40E-1 1.40E-1 8.90E-2 4.80E-2 4.60E-2 2.80E-2 1.60E-2 6.00E-3 5.00E-3 -1.00E-3    1.00E-3 3.00E-3 0.00E+0 0.00E+0 2.00E-3 1.00E-3
```

And the code:

```
        PROGRAM LECT

        REAL tot_count(42)

        CHARACTER (10) :: stringdate, date
        CHARACTER (8) :: stringtime,time
        CHARACTER (2) :: day, hour
        CHARACTER (2) :: month,minutes, seconds
        CHARACTER (4) :: year

        OPEN(2,FILE='date.dat')
        OPEN(6,FILE='test.txt', STATUS='UNKNOWN')

 1      READ(2,11,advance='yes',end=9)
     & stringdate, stringtime, (tot_count(I),I=1,42)

        day=stringdate(1:2)
        month=stringdate(4:5)
        year=stringdate(7:10)
        date=day//'/'//month//'/'//year

        hour=stringtime(1:2)
        minutes=stringtime(4:5)
        seconds=stringtime(7:8)
        time=hour//':'//minutes//':'//seconds

         WRITE(6,*) date,' ', time, (tot_count(I),I=1,42)

        GOTO 1

   11 FORMAT(A10,1X,A8,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X)
 9      CLOSE(2)
        CLOSE(6)

        END
```

Comment: The version tags is for specifying which version you want. There is not much reason using all of them, if you are not asking for differences between them.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use list-directed input for this rather than hardcoded formats.  First, I would change

```
11 FORMAT(A10,1X,A8,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X,
     & F7.2,1X,F7.2,1X)
```

into

```
11 format(A10,1X,A8,1X)
```

This is just enough format to read your line headers to grab the date and time.  Next, I would change

```
 1      READ(2,11,advance='yes',end=9)
     & stringdate, stringtime, (tot_count(I),I=1,42)
```

into

```
1  READ(2,11,advance='no',end=9) stringdate, stringtime
   read(2,*,end=9) (tot_count(I),I=1,42)
```

This will read the first two fields using the format specifier and not advance the line and then read the next 42 values using list-directed input.  Making these two changes and using your input data file produces the output:

```
 22/03/2015 00:00:43   25000.0000       1660.00000       2220.00000       2700.00000       3160.00000       3830.00000       3580.00000       3690.00000       3640.00000       245.000000       167.000000       36.4000015       15.6000004       7.46999979       3.21000004       2.08999991       1.48000002       1.38999999      0.774999976      0.720000029      0.605000019      0.644999981      0.490000010      0.365000010      0.330000013      0.145999998      0.108999997       6.10000007E-02   4.89999987E-02   4.10000011E-02   9.99999978E-03   8.99999961E-03   4.00000019E-03   1.00000005E-03   0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000    
 22/03/2015 16:14:35   12600.0000       836.000000       1120.00000       1360.00000       1590.00000       1920.00000       1800.00000       1850.00000       1830.00000       123.000000       83.5999985       20.5000000       9.86999989       5.01999998       2.83999991       1.88000000       1.49000001       1.72000003       1.05999994      0.833999991      0.822000027      0.572000027      0.460999995      0.222000003      0.277999997      0.358999997      0.239999995      0.140000001       8.90000015E-02   4.80000004E-02   4.60000001E-02   2.80000009E-02   1.60000008E-02   6.00000005E-03   4.99999989E-03  -1.00000005E-03   1.00000005E-03   3.00000003E-03   0.00000000       0.00000000       2.00000009E-03   1.00000005E-03
```

Comment: Just perfect. I do not see how I missed that. It's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed precisely-specifying input formats in your read statements can make them rather fragile.  Fortran's `*` list-directed reading would be ideal, let the compiler and run-time take care of the variability in the formatting of the real values, but those pesky dates and times would muck that up.

Hmmm, here's an idea.  Suppose that your lines are a maximum of 256 characters long

```
character(len=256) :: aline
...
read(2,*) aline
...
date = aline(1:10)
time = aline(12:19)
! decompose date and time into their elements if you want to
read(aline(20:256),*) tot_count
```

I've not tested this so there are almost certainly minor syntactical errors, but the approach is sound enough.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do some operations with tot_count. The mothod of casey works.